# CRM C# Loop to increment date by one month without affecting the day

Tags: c#, date, plugins, crm

I am making a loop where part of it will be creating new records and another part - should increment date field by one month without affecting the days, for every new record loop.

For example, default date is 2016/07/19 - dates for new records should go as follow - Record 1 - 2016/08/19; Record 2 - 2016/09/19; Record 3 - 2016/10/19

Here's a snippet of my code

```
startDate = (DateTime)target["xrm_startDate "];
while(a>b)
{
    startDate = startDate.AddMonth(1);
}
```

With this loop, date is being increased by one month, however days outputted are different, depending on how many days month has.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for?

```
startDate = new DateTime(startDate.Day, startDate.Addmonths(1).Month, startDate.Year)
```

Also please check for the year.

Comment: Should it be `startDate.Addmonths(1).Month` and `startDate.Year`?

Comment: This increases the month but outputted months starts from January and not from what was provided in `startDate = (DateTime)target["xrm_startDate "]; `

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard `DateTime.AddMonth` method. The [`DateTime.AddMonths`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) method returns a date a given number of months later, with the day-part corrected if that day is not valid:

> If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the
>   last valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st
>   + 1 month = April 30th